# Como obtener fecha de MySQL en un input

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día, en una tabla de mi base de datos almaceno entre otras cosas una fecha, y tengo el  siguiente formulario para actualizar datos, lo que busco es que la fecha que tengo almacenada en la base de datos se muestre en el input, intente con el código que esta ahí, pero no me muestra nada, gracias de antemano:

```
<form id="RegistroUsuario" action="updateTarea.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" onsubmit="return validarusu();">

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" id="registro">Modificar tarea</button> 

       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Nombres">Hora Final</label>
          <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="nom" required name="tfechafin" placeholder="" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($mostrar['fecha_fin'])) ?>">
      </div>
              
</form>
```

estoy trayendo el dato de esta consulta:

```
$id_mod = $_GET['id_tarea'];

$sql = "SELECT id_tarea, titulo, contenido, fecha_fin FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea = '$id_mod'";

$resultado = $db->query($sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
$mostrar = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

creo que la consulta esta bien porque me trae otros datos como el titulo y el contenido.

y así me muestra la fecha si la saco del input, lo cual quiere decir que la consulta funciona: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estas enviando `$mostrar['fecha_fin']`, edita la pregunta y coloca el dato, tal vez no lo esta enviando correctamente

Comment: @JuanRivera listo ya edite la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: @BetaM Gracias por tu respuesta, me podrías decir que función puedo usar o como documentarme? la verdad no se mucho de js, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

para mostrar tu fecha la cual tienes guardada en tu base de datos primero debes de hacer la consulta y tener listo el valor a para mostrarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$id_mod = $_GET['id_tarea'];

$sql = $db->query("SELECT *FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea = '$id_mod'");

$mostrar = $sql->fetch_assoc();

<input type="date" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($mostrar['fecha_fin']))">
```

Comment: la consulta esta bien, ya que me muestra la fecha si la saco del input y la pongo solo como echo de esta manera <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($mostrar['fecha_fin'])) ?>

Comment: puedes poner como te muestra la fecha fuera del input

Comment: por supuesto, acabo de editar la pregunta, el la imagen me muestra la fecha y hora, lo  cual no hace dentro del input.

Comment: cambia (d/m/Y H:i:s) por (d-m-Y) y el tipo de input (datetime-local) por (date)

Comment: no es viable, ya que necesito obtener la hora.

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de un error de formato de fecha muy típico a la par que tocapelotas en PHP.

La función strtotime devuelve un formato que no es compatible con datetime-local. Simplemente es adaptarlo con un *date* de PHP.

Prueba esto en el frontal (la query está bien):

```
<form id="RegistroUsuario" action="updateTarea.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" onsubmit="return validarusu();">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" id="registro">Modificar tarea</button> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Nombres">Hora Final</label>
        <?php
        // hay que dar un formato válido con datetime-local que utiliza el input posterior
        $fechaFinFormat = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($mostrar['fecha_fin']));
        ?>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="nom" required name="tfechafin" value="<?php echo $fechaFinFormat; ?>">
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Es decir, meter una modificación php para adaptar el formato de fecha que luego es la que vas a utilizar en el input.

Espero te ayude.

Saludos